# Different Elasticsearch results for the same query

Tags: elasticsearch

I've setup Elasticsearch with 1 cluster á 4 nodes.
Number of shards per index: 1; Number of replicas per index: 3

When I call a simple query like the following one multiple times I get different results (different total hits and different top 10 documents):

```
http://localhost:9200/index_name/_search?q=term
```

Different data on each shard? I like to have all shards up to date. What can I do?

This is the result of /_cluster/health:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "secret",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 4,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 4,
  "active_primary_shards" : 24,
  "active_shards" : 96,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0
}
```

As a temporary solution I rebuild the index through Ruby gem tire: ModelName.rebuild_index

But I need a long-term solution.

Comment: More details to your setup would be nice. Some information missing here is for example number of replicas per index, number of shards per node would also be nice to know.

Comment: Number of shards per index: 1 Number of replicas per index: 3 Where do I get the number of shards per node from? Cannot see it in my elasticsearch.yml.

Comment: Sorry, was shard per index. Seeing those I also don't really understand why you have a problem with this to be honest.

Comment: Can you post the output of cluster health? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html

Comment: I added the cluster health output to the description.

Comment: Looks like a split brain problem. I have a similar problem with two nodes even after recreating the index. Did you find out the root cause for this? Can you add some information on the workaround you used?
Possibly related topics: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723587
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899341/elasticsearch-different-results-for-searching-same-index-with-5-or-1-shards
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368791/elasticsearch-different-results-in-hits-total-and-num-docs
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/goFGavMj0mQ

Comment: I had a similar problem that has been solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402023/what-causes-different-search-results-for-same-elastic-search-query-on-two-nodes/30402153

Comment: If total hits are different, then you should investigate split-brain (see if there is a network partition).  The node you ran `/_cluster/health` on believes it's part of a 4-node cluster.  But run `/_cluster/health` on the other three to see if their stories agree.  It's possible that the others cannot see the entire cluster.

Comment: It's not unusual for your top hits to be different when querying different cluster nodes, since document-frequency is (by default) calculated at the node level per shard.  Try re-running your query with the slower  `&search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch` to test this (top docs should be identical).

Answer (score 15):

We ran into a similar problem and it turned out to be because Elasticsearch round-robins between different shards when searching. Each shard returns a slightly different `_score` because of slightly different indexing due to the way ES [handles deleted documents](https://www.elastic.co/blog/lucenes-handling-of-deleted-documents) in an index. In our case this meant similar results often placed slightly lower or higher in the results order, and, when combined with pagination (using `from` and `size` in the search query) it meant the same results were turning up on two separate "pages" or not at all from page to page.

We found an Elasticsearch [article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/consistent-scoring.html) on consistent scoring which explains this quite neatly and implemented a [`preference` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-preference.html) to ensure that we always get the same scores for a particular search by querying the same shards:

```
http://localhost:9200/index_name/_search?q=term&preference=blablabla
```

We also thought about using sorting, but Elasticsearch sorts results with the same scores by an internal Lucene document ID, ensuring that results with the same scores are always returned in the same order.

Answer (score 6):

This is because you don't have specified `sort` order and `size`. So every time you query you get random first 10 records as default `size` for result set by elasticsearch server is `10`.

You can add sorting in following way with curl,

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search' -d '{
 "query" : {
   ...
  },
   "sort" : [
     {"price" : {"order" : "asc", "mode" : "avg"}}
   ]
}'
```

Check [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) for for more info specially `from` and `size` with sort which is most mostly used for pagination.

**update:**

Though default sort is `score DESC` sometime it not works when records don't have relevant _score, as per http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting.html#_sorting

Comment: I should not have different total hits each time even without specifying sort and size.

When I don't specify sort then I get the prefered default sort which is "score DESC".

Comment: `score DESC` is correct but trouble is when two records has same score.

Comment: check this out http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_sorting.html when records don't have meaningful score it starts smelling.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909205/different-results-for-same-query-in-elasticsearch-cluster) helped me, as the answer says,

> One of the possible reasons could be distributed IDF, by default Elastic uses local IDF on each shard, to save some performance which will lead to different idfs across the cluster.

ES doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-is-broken.html)